# Rails 4: Re-Migrating all Migrations to Schema

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-4, migration

I am currently developing an Rails 4 app and over the last few months I collected a lot of unique migration files, which reverse their own changes, etc.
Since I have no problem to reset the db at this stage of development, I thought I could might clean up this mess a bit.
**Is there a way of redoing all migration files, while also allowing to delete certain migration-files and to expand others?**

I appreciate each answer!

**Example (Edit)**

I have two migration files:

1. *20160911071103_create_items.rb*
2. *20160918085621_add_cached_votes_to_items.rb*

Both are already migrated.<

*1st file before*

```
class CreateItems < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :items do |t|

      t.integer :user_id

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

My goal is to include the added column by the second file directly in the first file and deleting the second.

*1st file after*

```
class CreateItems < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :items do |t|

      t.integer :user_id
      t.integer :cached_votes

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: not sure what do you mean by **redoing all migration files** ? You can give actual example of your application, I think that would make more sense!

Comment: @dkp added an example

Comment: `rake db:reset`

Comment: I would argue that there is no need at all to keep old migration files. Once the migrations were run in all environments, you are save to delete them. Your current database scheme is store in the `schema.rb` anyway. That file is used to setup the test database. And new developer will usually start with a database dump or can use the `schema.rb` too. Why do you want to maintain old migrations? What do you try to achieve?

Comment: @spickermann If possible in any way, I would basically like to start of with a blank schema again, and then migrating all my changed migration files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run

`rake db:migrate:down VERSION=20160918085621`

`rake db:migrate:down VERSION=20160911071103`

You can now check the migration status by `rake db:migrate:status` and you should expect to get migration status as follows:

```
down 20160911071103
down 20160918085621
```

Now, you can remove the migration file `20160918085621_add_cached_votes_to_items.rb`

& edit the migration file `20160911071103_create_items.rb` as you need.

And, finally run:

`rake db:migrate:up VERSION=20160911071103`

Answer (score 0):

As you are saying you it's on development only so you can change the migration files.

**NOTE:** It is not recommended to edit your migration but as it's not deployed anywhere so you can do it.

**20160911071103_create_items.rb**

```
class CreateItems < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :items do |t|

      t.integer :user_id

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

**20160918085621_add_cached_votes_to_items.rb**

```
class AddCachedVotesToItems < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :items, :cached_votes, :integer
  end
end
```

Modify your first migration and remember to delete second migration.

**20160911071103_create_items.rb (Migration 1 + Migration 2)**

```
class CreateItems < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :items do |t|

      t.integer :user_id
      t.integer :cached_votes

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

And then `Drop` and `Migrate` again

```
rake db:drop # Drop the db

rake db:setup # Create and migrate the db
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have a working `schema.rb` file. you can just generate a migration file

`bundle exec rails generate migration CreateItemsNew`

Then fill the codeblock `create_table "items"` from your working `schema.rb` to this newly generated migration file. Then do a bulk search for all the migrations in your `db/migrate` that changes the table `items` and delete those files. This way you'll have a single migration file for a table in your db.